# Equivalence Classes $12$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Given the following...

Let $Q=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\dotsc,26\}$ and let $P$ be the non-empty subsets of $Q$. For $A\in P$  and $B\in P$, $A\sim B$ iff there is a bijection $f\colon A\to B$.

How would I describe (not list) the set $A\in P$ when $A\sim\{1,2,3,4,5\}$?

And how many equivalence classes would the whole relation have?

Comment: What do you know about the sizes of two sets $A$ and $B$, if there is a bijection between them?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I don't know the size of either, only that there is a bijection f:A->B

Comment: All right, I'll frame my question again : If there is a bijection from $B$ to $\{ 1,2,3,4,5\}$, what is the size of $B$?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bijection between two finite sets $A$ and $B$ then they have the same number of elements. The converse is also true.

So if  $A \sim \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ (that is there exists a bijection from $A$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$) then $A$ is any subset of $Q$ containing $5$ elements.

For any subset of size $0<k \leq 26$ there is a equivalence class containing all such $k$-subsets. So there are $26$ equivalence classes.